# Kivy Does Not Output Plain Text, Only Object Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, file-io, kivy

So I was trying to create a very basic text editor in Kivy. So I had got around the issue of text not showing up (via lambda). However, a new error appeared on the horizon; saving. I want to save automatically to a plain txt file. However, my current code only save an object (is it a pointer?) of the actual text input. Thank you all, SO!

```
    import kivy
    import os
    kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    class ColdKivyApp(App): # I actually used to call it Zone but changed it to Cold cause it's cold outside ;)
            def build(self):
                    f = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
                    txt = TextInput(multiline=True, cursor_blink=True, background_color=(1,1,1,1))
                    f.add_widget(txt)
                    txtstr = str(txt)
                    Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(txt, "focus", True))
                    with open('testtxt.txt', 'w') as txtwriter:
                        txtwriter.write("" + txtstr)
                        txtwriter.close()
                    return f

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ColdKivyApp().run()
```

Edit: Spelling

Comment: As mentioned in Tshirtman's answer, use `txt.text` to access the text of your `txt` variable. You can also set their text using `txt.text = 'foo'`. Other kivy widgets that can use `.text` include buttons and labels.

Answer (score 0):

TextInput has a `text` property, that's where the current content is.

Comment: so how to write it into a txt file?

Comment: just the usual way in python: `with open(filename, 'w') as fd: fd.write(text)`

Comment: there is no way to help you if you don't clarify what doesn't work, (code that breaks, which error you get, etc)

Comment: No text output, file is created but the text is not written. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `txtstr = str(txt)` in your code to `txtstr = txt.text`.