# How to transfer TextInput to pandas data and write it to an excel sheet? Kivy

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

So I am having an issue using pandas with kivy to update/create an excel sheet. I want to take the user input from the kivy frame and save it to a variable containing a pandas DataFrame. From there, I want to write it to an excel sheet. The problem is, TextInput will only spit out the user input as a memory address so pandas module can't access the information to write it to a file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import pandas

class MainWindow(Screen):
    first_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    last_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    level = ObjectProperty(None)


    def btn(self):
        self.L = ()
        print("First: " + self.first_name.text,
              "Last: " + self.last_name.text,
              "Level: " + self.level.text)

        self.L = pandas.DataFrame({str(self.first_name) + str(self.last_name): self.level})

        self.first_name.text = ''
        self.last_name.text = ''
        self.level.text = ''
        print(self.L)
        with pandas.ExcelWriter('student_info.xlsx') as writer:
            self.L.to_excel(writer)




class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my2.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

In the first print statement, the desired information is printed but once I put that information into a dictionary, the dictionary is printed with only the object locations. I don't understand what is changing when putting these strings into the dictionary.

The Kivy Language File:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    first_name: first
    last_name: last
    level: level

    GridLayout
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Student First Name: "
            TextInput:
                id: first
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Student Last Name: "
            TextInput:
                id: last
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Student Level: "
            TextInput:
                id: level
                multiline: False

        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.btn()
        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                font_size: 25
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
                text: ">"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom": 1}

            Button:
                font_size: 25
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
                text: "<"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                pos_hint: {"left":1, "bottom": 1}



<SecondWindow>
    name: "second"

    Button:
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: "<"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        pos_hint: {"left":1, "bottom": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

So a little while after posting this I was able to find the answer via this post:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900269/kivy-does-not-output-plain-text-only-object-location)

A little embarrassed that it took me 5 hours to figure out such a minor detail but hey, what can you do.